# Is there a way to trigger a Jenkins job from "execute shell" of another Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have three Jenkins jobs. The first job has "execute bash" as a build step. The bash script has if/else statement. And based on this if/else I need to trigger the other two jobs. Is there a way in the "execute shell" to trigger other jobs?

Comment: Instead of bash script having conditions, use Conditional Build Steps plugin to have conditions and trigger the Job whichever you want from the conditions.

Comment: If you want, you can use Build Remote trigger with ```curl``` in the shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the `Execute Shell` , you can execute any shell command (including `curl`). 
You can trigger an existing job with `curl`. e.g.

`curl -X POST http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/job/jobname/build --user foo:foo_token`

Comment: When I do this, I get ```<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```